# react-native ImageEditor.cropImage causes Error : ExifInterface only supports saving attributes on JPEG formats

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native ImageEditor for image cropping as follows,

```
ImageEditor.cropImage(imageUri,
  {
         offset: { x: 0, y: 0 },
         size: { width: response.width, height: response.height },
         displaySize: { width: 50, height: 50 },
         resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  (uri) => { resolve(uri); console.log('resolved uri', resolve(uri));},
  (error) => {console.log('error', error)},
);
```

but encountered with following error,

```
ExifInterface only supports saving attributes on JPEG formats.
```

This is happening with both JPEG and PNG images.

I am using "react-native": "0.54.2"

Not sure whether it is problem with `react-native` or `android`.

Any help is appreciated.